# I get "lost connection" error while using ssh and scp

Tags: shell-script, scp

```
mySCP="scp -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o HostbasedAuthentication=no"

rm -Rf /tmp/logdata
mkdir /tmp/logdata

$mySCP -r xyz2384:/d/d1/run_logs/results/trail/log.txt /tmp/logdata/
myResult=$?

if (( $myResult == 0 )); then
    echo "SUCCESS – Log data copying, at $(date +'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')."
else
    echo "**FAILED – Log data copying, at $(date +'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')."
    echo "$myResult"
    exit
fi
```

When I execute this as part of a script, sometimes I get a "`lost connection`" error and the execution of the script terminates, but sometimes it works.

Is there some way to check the connection availability and retry until everything executes successfully?

Comment: You are catching the return code, can't you just loop around if it errors?

Comment: I fixed the markup and the code to some extent (some parts would not work as you had written them). Since you say it works, just that it gives you a connection error, I assume that you have just had problems pasting the code. I added white space for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your code works:

```
mySCP="scp -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o HostbasedAuthentication=no"

rm -Rf /tmp/logdata
mkdir /tmp/logdata

myCmd="$mySCP -r xyz2384:/d/d1/run_logs/results/trail/log.txt /tmp/logdata/"

while true; do
    $myCmd
    myResult=$?
    date=$(date +'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    if [ $myResult -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "SUCCESS – Log data copying, at $date."
        break
    else
        echo "**FAILED – Log data copying, at $date."
        echo "mySCP return code: $myResult"
        echo "Retrying..."
        # You can probably increase this delay
        sleep 10
    fi
done
```